# Creating a Battery using azobenzene in High School

Tags: stereochemistry

I’m doing a project on isomerization in high school and have stumbled across the studies involving azobenzene in energy storage using its photoisomeric properties and sunlight . Do you think that this is something I could show in a high school lab, if not I can create a design, but it would be cool to show this phenomenon to classmates/teachers as my project. What do you experienced chemists think about this, as I am not sure if it is feasible.

Comment: Answer below lets bits of hope. I up voted it becsuse is informative. But a straight answer is no, you can't.

Answer (score 4):

Azobenzenes are among the most widely studied molecular photoswitches, yet, I'm not sure this is a project capable of doing in a high school lab. It probably need sophisticated instruments (*e.g.*, azobenzene needs to be covalently bound to carbon nanotubes (CNTs)) and has done previously, notably by Department of Materials Science and Engineering in Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT) (Ref.1). Yet, I'd encourage you to consult people who know the field (such as Prof. Timothy J. Kucharski at MIT and Harvard) and get some advice how to do it in a laboratory environment or do a oral presentation (that would be cool as well). I'll attached some figures of Ref.1 for your convenience here:

**Figure 1:** Synthesis and characterization of azobenzene-functionalized SWCNTs (Adapted from reference 1. Copyright @ 2014 *Nature* Publishing Group).
[image: Synthesis and characterization of azobenzene]

**Figure 2:** Photochemical charging and thermal energy release (Adapted from reference 1. Copyright @ 2014 *Nature* Publishing Group).
[image: thermal energy release]

**Figure 3:** Photochemical and thermal cycling (Adapted from reference 1. Copyright @ 2014 *Nature* Publishing Group).
[image: Photochemical and thermal cycling]

**Figure 4:** Effect of packing photochemical switches in the solid state (Adapted from reference 1. Copyright @ 2014 *Nature* Publishing Group).
[image: photochemical switches in the solid state]

Also read Ref.2 for more information on molecular solar thermal energy storage using chemicals other than azobenzene, which also included.

References:

1. T. J. Kucharski, N. Ferralis, A. M. Kolpak, J. O. Zheng, D. G. Nocera, J. C. Grossman, “Templated assembly of photoswitches significantly increases the energy-storage capacity of solar thermal fuels,” *Nature Chemistry* **2014**, *6*, 441–447 (DOI: 10.1038/NCHEM.1918).
2. A. Lennartson, A. Roffey, K. Moth-Poulsen, “Designing photoswitches for molecular solar thermal energy storage,” *Tetrahedron Letters* **2015**, *56(12)*, 1457–1465 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tetlet.2015.01.187).